# htaccess issue when i try to access a directory

Tags: .htaccess

So here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?weblink=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /error [L,R=301]
```

It's simple so when I try to access host/product-name it works but when I try to access for example a directory /blog or /blog/ redirect pe to error page specified by last rule. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?weblink=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule . /error [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is because of the trailing slash (it generates a virtual directory). You have 2 possibilities: the first one is to avoid the trailing slash in your rule (remove `/?` before `$`) or the second one is to add this code in `product.php` right after `<head>` html tag: `<base href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/">`. But in both case, you should avoid having rule accepting trailing slash or not (this leads to duplicate content)